# BootStrap Grid System Issues

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, fluid

I am having some issues with the bootstrap grid system.

I usually use fluid layout for my projects and have no issues. I am using the NON-FLUID layout, and somehow, my project only spans for about half the page, somehow not centering.

Any help?

Link: http://tsa.aws.af.cm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add one **Div** with class `container` as below mention

**as like this**

```
<div class="container"> // add this line 
<div class="span12">
         <video id="video_background" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop" muted="" volume="0">  <source src="videos/splash.ogv" type="video/ogg ogv" ;="" codecs="theora, vorbis"><source src="videos/splash.mp4" type="video/mp4"> Video not supported </video>
         <h1 class="text-center">Monta Vista TSA grows careers and accelerates lives</h1><br>
         <p class="text-center">See what our <a href="#">members think</a> and <a href="join.html">join now</a></p>
        </div>
</div> // add this line
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this fixed it. Though, why does it fix it? Usually, in fluid, I don't need containers.

Comment: you define one div those width is fixed than used to media query for responsive design ...

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    ...
  </div>
</body>
```

This the example given for fixed width layout, can you double check your code.